# How can i add border to a form box ?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

i want to add border to the bootstrap form box.i had added border style properties but its not working . suggest please

thia is the form box class:

```
<div class="form-box">
                   <div class="form-top">
                                <div class="form-top-left">
```

And this is the css :

```
.form-box {
    margin-top: 0px;
      border-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: #50e54b;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Seems to work fine with the existing border or just applying a new one https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/PKWEwp

Answer (score 1):

Because of other classes, use the "!important"

```
border: solid 2px #50e54b!important;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add border to your box by using the border CSS property **[border]**(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Here's an example usage:

```
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
```

The code above will add a solid border of 1px in thickness and white in colour.

Click the link above to see more about the border property.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the code works fine. But if you want you can add an 8px padding so the content has room for placement instead of being crammed in there with the border. By the way, a 2px or 4px border radius looks better for the border, but it's up to you.

```
.form-box {
  padding: 8px; /*makes it look neat*/
  border-radius: 4px; /*or 2px*/
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```